# Test with pre-trained model in Caffe, accuracy lower than test phase while training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I trained a ResNet-50 model in Caffe. When I use the Python interface of Caffe to test image one by one, the accuracy is lower than the testing phase while training the model.
That is to say, when I change the images into LMDB format, and test with the pre-trained model in command line, the accuracy is higher than I test the images one by one.

The essential Python code:

```
net = caffe.Net('Resnet-50-deploy.prototxt', 'resnet_50_600000.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
transformer.set_transpose('data', (2, 0, 1))
transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255)
#imagepath is from a while loop
image = caffe.io.load_image(imagepath)
transformed_img = transformer.preprocess('data', image)
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformed_img
output = net.forward()
```

Why is the accuracy different? I am sure that the images are same.